How to pass a file to video widget in GJS/GTK4
I'm trying to add basic video playback to a Gnome app. This is my first Gnome app, and I'm using GJS + GTK4.
Ultimately there'll be about 10 video files (local mp4 files) throughout the app. I have the GTK video component (GTKvideo) wrapped with my own widget ("FbrVideoWidget"). For now, I have one test instance of the widget on the initial view of the app. As far as I can tell, the widget renders (I just see black, which I believe is the video player without controls or a file).
PROBLEM
When attempting to apply the file to the video player instance, I don't see any log warnings about success/failure, and when logging the video instance, it still appears like an empty object (before and after). So I don't know if I'm not accessing the video element correctly or not passing a file correctly.
Side note, after the file attempt, I'm also trying to start playback programmatically, and this does produce a log error:
(org.example.filebrowser:2): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:04:54.116: Media stream of type 'GtkNoMediaFile' does not implement GtkMediaStream::play

This actually seems like a good sign to me because I interpret this as the video element is actually loaded but it doesn't have a proper video source.
QUESTION Given my requirement (playing local mp4 files), where should the mp4 files be kept?
QUESTION Regardless of where the file lives, do I absolutely need to register them somewhere? I suppose this depends on how I'm trying to get the files in the app.
QUESTION How do you get-and-pass a local file into the video player, via a widget wrapping?
I see different methods and no clear answer.
// Get path to mp4 file in my OS home dir
const filepath = GLib.build_filenamev([GLib.get_home_dir(), value]);
log('filepath is: ', filepath);

// 1 - Apply video file: new_for_uri
this._videoActual.file = Gio.File.new_for_uri(filepath);

// 2 - Apply video file: new_for_path
//this._videoActual.file = Gio.File.new_for_path(filepath);

/// --- or ---

// 3 - Apply video file: set_resource
// Tried accessing a resource defined in data/ui/
// this._videoActual.set_resource('/org/example/filebrowser/ui/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4')


RELEVANT CODE
I'm excluding registry files.
/src/VideoWidget.js
import GObject from 'gi://GObject';
import Gtk from 'gi://Gtk';
import Gio from "gi://Gio";
import GLib from 'gi://GLib';

export const VideoWidget = GObject.registerClass({
    GTypeName: 'FbrVideoWidget',
    CssName: 'video',
    Template: 'resource:///org/example/filebrowser/ui/VideoWidget.ui',
    InternalChildren: ['videoActual'],
    Properties: {
        VideoFile: GObject.ParamSpec.string(
            'video-file', // name
            'Video File', // nick
            'The text displayed by the widget', // blurb
            GObject.ParamFlags.READWRITE, // flags
            '' // default value
        ),
    }
}, class extends Gtk.Widget {

    constructor(params={}) {
        super(params);

        log('Video mounted');

    }

    get videoFile() {
        log('get videoFile(): ', this._videoFile);
        return this._videoFile;
    }

    set videoFile(value) {

        // Setting local stuff
        log('set videoFile() value: ', value);
        if (this._videoFile === value) return;
        this._videoFile = value;

        // Getting filepath of requested video file
        const filepath = GLib.build_filenamev([GLib.get_home_dir(), value]);
        log('filepath is: ', filepath);

        // Apply file to video player using new_for_uri
        this._videoActual.file = Gio.File.new_for_uri(filepath);

        // Apply file to video player using new_for_path
        //this._videoActual.file = Gio.File.new_for_path(filepath);

        // Or trying to use declared app resource (declared in `org.example.filebrowser.data.gresource.xml`):
this._videoActual.set_resource('/org/example/filebrowser/ui/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4')

        
        //this._videoActual.set_autoplay(true);

        // LOG ERROR OCCURS HERE
        this._videoActual.media_stream.play();

        this.notify('video-file');
    }

});

/data/ui/VideoWidget.ui
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
    <template class="FbrVideoWidget">
        <property name="layout-manager">
            <object class="GtkBoxLayout">
                <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            </object>
        </property>
        <object class="GtkBox">
            <property name="orientation">1</property>
            <property name="halign">3</property>
            <child>
                <object class="GtkVideo" id="videoActual">
                    <property name="file" />
                    <property name="autoplay">true</property>
                    <property name="loop">true</property>
                    <property name="width-request">540</property>
                    <property name="height-request">540</property>
                </object>
            </child>
        </object>
    </template>
</interface>

Test instance of the video widget (initial view in the app)
<property name="child">
    <object class="FbrVideoWidget" id="videoTest">
        <property name="video-file">file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4</property>
    </object>
</property>

App resources declared in org.example.filebrowser.data.gresource.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gresources>
    <gresource prefix="/org/example/filebrowser">
        <file>css/style.css</file>
        <file>ui/VideoWidget.ui</file>
        <file>ui/WelcomeWidget.ui</file>
        <file>ui/Window.ui</file>
        <file>ui/file_example_MP4_640_3MG.mp4</file>
    </gresource>
    <gresource prefix="/org/example/filebrowser/icons/scalable/actions">
        <file alias="filebrowser-welcome-symbolic.svg">icons/welcome-symbolic.svg</file>
    </gresource>
</gresources>



Ok, the first step is to write the custom widget that will later be instantiated in the tabs. Here we have a problem, which is the absence of "parent = ", and a strange thing that seems unnecessary to me:
<property name="layout-manager">
   <object class="GtkBoxLayout">
       <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
   </object>
</property>

The The corrected version would be:
/data/ui/VideoWidget.ui
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <template class="FbrVideoWidget" parent="GtkBox">
    <property name="orientation">1</property>
    <property name="halign">3</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkVideo" id="videoActual">
        <property name="autoplay">true</property>
        <property name="loop">true</property>
        <property name="width-request">540</property>
        <property name="height-request">540</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </template>
</interface>

I have no experience with GJS but the instantiation seems correct except for the "Properties" part, I don't know if it is correct or not but it doesn't seem necessary. Which leaves us with:
export const VideoWidget = GObject.registerClass({
    GTypeName: 'FbrVideoWidget',
    CssName: 'video',
    Template: 'resource:///org/example/filebrowser/ui/VideoWidget.ui',
    InternalChildren: ['videoActual'],
}, class FbrVideoWidget extends Gtk.Box...

In this case, to access the video's "file" property, instead of:
this._videoFile = value;

he would be
this._videoActual.file = value;

I don't have enough knowledge in GJS to check the rest, but I believe these two points are the main ones. I tested this /data/ui/VideoWidget.ui with the basic Python code to load the video and it worked.

Thanks for the suggestions; I now see player controls regularily, so the video element is rendering, however still there is no video playing (just black with controls). NEW CLUE: When hovering the broken player, I see this error: "GTK could not find a media module. Check your installation.". Searching this, I find clues about GStreamer and other libraries, which I've installed. Still no change.

Discovered GTK inspector (yes, I'm new) and in global settings it reports "Media Backend: none". I suspect I have explicitly tell GTK about my media backend (I have GStreamer installed)... but where do I do that?
